# Boot Win from another computer on mac using external disk and Parallels?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, parallels-desktop, ntfs

I have Win 7 laptop and mbp. I removed disk from Win laptop and plugged on mbp as external disk. Windows 7 is on NTFS partition. Since I have NTFS for Mac by Paragon I can read/write to that partition.

On Parallels I choose `Use Windows from Boot Camp`, hit `Continue` and reached what is shown by the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What else may I try in order to boot that Win 7 on mbp?

Comment: I haven't tried anything like this in far too long to hope to make this a real answer, but Win7 really doesn't like being booted from an external disk, even when done properly. I'd try the Migrate from PC option instead. The resulting VDMK you should be able to copy anywhere, once you got it working.

Comment: The problem is that I only have the disk right now, the laptop is on another country. And it looks like some kind of Transponder Agent should be installed on the PC beforehand.

Comment: Well, you asked it to assume you were starting from a Bootcamp volume, which would already have everything necessary to boot into the Mac as an internal disk running Windows - so that's just not going to be what the system expects it to be at all.